# How can I select with jQuery elements that have been included using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a menu that gets added using this function:

```
function loadContent() { 
    $(".navbar").load("navigation.html"); 
}
```

navigation.html looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="home.html" class="first">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="charts.html" class="last">Energy Charts</a></li>
</ul>
```

but when I try to select something in that menu and add a class, let's say:

```
$('.navbar a').addClass('activeState');
```

it doesn't work in Chrome, I think because the DOM needs to be refreshed or something, I really don't know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wait for the content to actually load. Put your code in the `load` callback function:

```
function loadContent() { 
    $(".navbar").load("navigation.html", function () {
        $('.navbar a').addClass('activeState');
    }); 
}
```

---

As pointed out by @LifeInTheGrey, you should use a separate function for better performance:

```
function loadContent() { 
    $(".navbar").load("navigation.html", actOnContent); 
}

function actOnContent () {
    $('.navbar a').addClass('activeState');
}
```

---

You should also look into selector caching...

Comment: upvoted, but ideally you would call an external function that performed that procedure... $('.navbar').load('navigation.html',addActiveState);, where addActiveState was the name of the function that added the class.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey that depends on if the function is to be called from multiple handlers. Leaving as an anon. function is fine for single use instances IMO.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Given that this code is in a wrapper `loadContent`, I'd assume its being called multiple times.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - yes, and also it can only be done that way if parameters need to be passed. But if the function is called multiple times (as most are), then external is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Any code that depends on AJAX-loaded content MUST be placed in the success handler of said AJAX request. In the case of `.load()`, that is the third argument:

```
$(".navbar").load("navigation.html",null,function() {
    $(".navbar a").addClass("activeState");
});
```

Comment: The second parameter is optional. Why are you passing in `null`?

Comment: Because I don't like optional parameters in the middle and having the underlying framework have to guess what I mean.

Comment: If you don't like that, you should probably let go of jQuery... They use "optional parameters in the middle" for most of their API.

Comment: I don't use jQuery, never have and never will ;)

Comment: OK. But, is it too much to ask that when you're answering a jQuery question you should stay within the jQuery thought-process?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on document ready function:

```
$('.navbar').delegate('a', 'click', function() { 
  $(this).addClass('activeState');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function loadContent() { 
    $(".navbar").load("navigation.html", addAttribute); 
}

function addAttribute() {
    $('.navbar a').addClass('activeState');
}
```